# Could not find class 'com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.ObjectPersister'

Tags: android, robospice

After migrating my project from eclipse to android studio 2.2,I am getting this issue,any help to resolve this issue?

**E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.ObjectPersister', referenced from method com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.CacheManager.addPersister**

my **build.gradle** is

```
compile files('libs/commons-io-1.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
compile files('libs/robospice-1.4.11.jar')
compile files('libs/robospice-cache-1.4.11.jar')
compile files('libs/robospice-google-http-client-1.4.11.jar')
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your *.jar files are in the libs folder on your project root

Comment: Tropper,yes all files are present in lib/ folder

Comment: I suppose you didn't forgot the  `import com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.ObjectPersister ` on the begin of your class

Comment: Im getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.octo.android.robospice.priority.PausablePriorityBlockingQueue` error from robospice.1.4.11-sources.jar.any idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/robospice/7oTKc4xtlKg/wm6Do1hmN5AJ this one gets the same error maybe it helps u :)

Comment: package com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.exception does not exist